# java-Thymeleaf: how get next date?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I want list like:

```
<ul>
  <li>2017-01-31</li> <!-- I want today date -->
  <li>2017-02-01</li> <!-- I want tomorrow date -->
  <li>2017-02-02</li> <!-- I want next day date -->
</ul>
```

Now I have only first `li`:

```
<ul>
  <li>th:text="${#dates.format(#dates.createToday(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')</li>
</ul>
```

How to get next date ( like: `#dates.createToday() + "1 day"`)?

Comment: I'm sorry buddy. I couldn't get you are trying to explain. Could explain more...

Comment: i edit question. Now it's vary Simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that thymeleaf just doesn't do well... that being said, if you include common-lang3 in your pom, you can get it working like this:

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Thymeleaf:

```
    <ul>
        <li th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0,2)}" th:with="util=${T(org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils)},date=${util.addDays(#dates.createToday(), i)}" th:text="${#dates.format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" />
    </ul>
```

I would recommend that you add the dates in your controller (creating them in the java, which is easy), and then just loop and format in thymeleaf.